# Replacing Column Names without typing the actual column names

Tags: r

Simple but frustrating problem here:
I've imported xls data into R, which unfortunately is the only current way to get the data - no csv option or direct DB query.

Anyways - I'm looking to do quite a bit of manipulation on this data set, however the variable names are extraordinarily messy: ie. col2 = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\r XXXXXX YYYYY ZZZZZZ" - you get my gist. Each column head has an equally messy name as this example and there are typically >15 columns per spreadsheet.

Ideally I'd like to program a name manipulation solution via R to avoid manually changing the names in xls prior to importing. But I can't seem to find the right solution, since every R function I try/check requires the column name be spelled out and set to a new variable. Spelling out the entire column name is tedious and impractical and plus the special characters seem to break R's functions anyways.

Does anyone know how to do a global replace all names or a global rename by column number rather than name?

I've tried
replace()
for loops
lapply()

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Expected output would be useful, and also some explanation of exactly how complex your renaming scheme would be. Just from what you've written it isn't clear why `setNames` or `names(df) <- c(...)` wouldn't suffice, or doing the latter for specific indices: `names(df)[1] <- "foo"`. All of these are standard ways of setting names in R. Why don't they work for you?

Comment: Have you looked at the [janitor-package](http://sfirke.github.io/janitor/)?

Comment: Desired output example would be something extremely simple, i.e: "\r\r\r\r\r\n\n\n\n\n\n XXXX YYYY ZZZZ" to "x_y_z"

Answer (score 0):

Remove non-printing characters in the first `gsub`.  Then trim whitespace off the ends using `trimws` and replace consecutive strings of the same character with just one of them in the second `gsub`.  No packages are used.

```
# test input
d <- data.frame("\r\r\r\r\r\n\n\n\n\n\n XXXX YYYY ZZZZ" = 0, check.names = FALSE)

names(d) <- trimws(gsub("[^[:print:]]", "", names(d)))
names(d) <- gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", names(d))

d
##       X Y Z
##     1     0
```

With R 3.6 or later you could consider replacing the first `gsub` line with this `trimws` line:

```
names(d) <- trimws(names(d), "both", "\\s")
```

If you want syntactic names add this after the above code:

```
names(d) <- make.names(names(d))

d
##   X.Y.Z
## 1     0
```